# Reference for a couple of terms, $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}_X(-,-)$ and $\boxtimes$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I have a couple of questions on symbols.

> What are the names for $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}_X( \mathscr{F},\mathscr{G})$ for sheaves on a scheme $X$, and $\boxtimes$? 
>   And what would be a good reference(s) I can look up these terms?

Comment: The first one is the hom sheaf, the second one is the external tensor product.